# How exactly could we provide a seamless automated method of key generation to the application that **operates across all shards**

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sharding

http://www.dbshards.com/articles/database-sharding-whitepapers/:

> Auto-increment key management. Typical auto-increment functionality
>   provided by database management systems generate a sequential key for
>   each new row inserted into the database. This is fine for a single
>   database application, but when using Database Sharding, keys must be
>   managed across all shards in a coordinated fashion. The requirement
>   here is to provide a seamless, automated method of key generation to
>   the application, one that operates across all shards, ensuring that
>   keys are unique across the entire system.

I cannot understand how exactly could we provide a seamless automated method of key generation to the application that **operates across all shards**.

I have heard of using GUID, but [since GUID isn't guaranteed to be unique across different machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766033/if-2-different-databases-on-the-same-machine-runs-newid-is-it-guaranteed-that), I do not see how that is going to work *reliably*

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL you can use the server variables [auto_increment_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) and [auto_increment_offset](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_offset) to have different servers generate different Ids to avoid collisions.  It is entirely up to you to configure your properly servers so that you don't end up with duplicate values.

Comment: the problem is that to configure properly the servers so we don't end up with duplicate values requires talking to all the shards. not very efficient isn't it?

Comment: No, each instance is configured differently.  If you have 6 servers, A through F, then each one has a local configuration file setting their offset to a unique value of 1 through 6, and you can set the increment to any value you want (an even multiple of 10 would probably help keep your sanity up for identifying which server a particular record came from, if you ever need that).

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for a distributed database system I developed, all problems went away when I switch to using GUIDs as primary unique identifiers. I highly recommend them. Not only do you fine identifiers are unique within a single key definition data domain, but you will fine that you can have universal tables that reference multiple domains.

I have also learn not to rely on business data for a true unique key in the database, customers think these keys are unique but there are always incidents when they want to change them and many times have an undefined situation.