# if 2 different databases on the same machine runs NEWID(),  Is it guaranteed that there will never be a clash?

Tags: sql-server, database

if 2 **different** databases on the same machine runs NEWID(),

Is it guaranteed that there will never be a clash?

Comment: I think you need to at a lot more detail here.  I'm assuming you are talking about MS SQL Server but its not clear.  Also its usually helpful to post some code so users can get an idea what context you are talking about.

Answer (score 5):

It is unique enough, statistically. The world will end before you have a collision.

GUID is mandatory in most replication scenarios where many machines send data to each other: you can't set up replication without a GUID. So of course it's safe to use on many machines

Answer (score 2):

`NEWID()` values are generated randomly. Although, statistically, there is a *chance* that the values returned by `NEWID()` could collide, based on *all* machines generating values worldwide, you need to worry about more probable events, such as your entire server spontaneously combusting.

---

On a single Windows machine, there's a single Windows function responsible for the values which become available through the `NEWID()` function, and it's even less likely to produce two identical values in a row than any two random machines doing so - so the probability is *lower* that two calls on different databases on the same machine will produce the same value.

Answer (score 1):

NEWID() is a uniqueidenifier in SQL Server, which is 16-byte GUID.

See
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx
and
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding (although I cannot verify) that NEWID() uses the RPC UUIDCreate to generate a unique GUID that is derived from the MAC address of the machine, a random number and the date and time stamp. Also UUIDCreate is specifically designed to return a unique ID for every call. I have yet to encounter any problems. Since many features, including Active Directory, is very dependent on unique GUIDs, I am fairly certain that Microsoft makes sure this method does indeed produce unique identifiers across machines. The only risk I know of is when there are two machines with the same MAC address. Maybe someone can locate the specific documentation that defines the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

NEWID will be unique to your machine, but not necessarily unique to all machines everywhere.

Comment: if 2 **different** databases on the same machine runs NEWID(),

Is it guaranteed that there will never be a clash?

Answer (score 0):

[`NEWID()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) is a non-deterministic function in SQL Server that returns a unique value of type `uniqueidentifier`. MSDN docs explicitly state: "returns a unique value".

You can use it like this:

```
DECLARE @foo uniqueidentifier = NEWID();
SELECT @foo;
```

You can also use it as a default column value in a table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL  DEFAULT newid(),
)
```

The chances that the server would generate the same GUID on 2+ databases is very small. Too small to worry about. To explore/test/confirm this, you'd have to analyze the `NEWID()` implementation.